# Find the range of $f:(-4,6) \rightarrow R$ , $f(x):x^2 -4x +1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

When i work over finding the range of a function , my textbook gives me a solution way such that if $f:(-3,2] \rightarrow R$ , $f(x):x^2 -2$ then its range can be found such that $-3<x \leq 2 \rightarrow 0 \leq x^2 < 9 \rightarrow -2 \leq x^2 -2 <  7$. It is fine , but when i want to apply it another question , it gave me wrong answer.

Question: Find the range of $f:(-4,6) \rightarrow R$ , $f(x):x^2 -4x +1$

My work : $-4<x<6 \rightarrow 0 \leq x^2 < 36$  , $-4<x<6 \rightarrow-24 < -4x < 16 $, and $-23 < x^2 -4x +1 < 53$

However , the answer is $[-3,33)$ .Why didnt the previous solution way work ? Why isnt the answer $(-23,53)$ ?

Comment: what bound you got is correct but it is not enough it can be made stronger

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore yeah , ı know that the range consists of global max and global min , but book gives this solution way for solution , it worked for the rest except for this

Comment: Are you sure it's $x^2-2$ and not $(x-2)^2$?  The book's idea is maybe that you know what the maxes/mins are for a parabola; depending on which way it's pointing, the maxes/mins are gonna be at the vertex and the endpoints of the domain interval.  What they're doing with $(x - 2)^2$ is completing the square, writing $f(x) = (x-2)^2 - 3$.  So solve your problem with the parabola, then just shift everything down by three.

Comment: @JohnSamples , what i wonder is that is this solution way reliable ? i thought that i should use calculus knowledge such as critial points etc. for this type of question instead of recommendation of book

Comment: The method you use where you do 'each term' and them sum them at the end won't be a reliable method, because these different functions $g(x) = x^2$, $h(x) = -4x$ and $j(x) = 1$ can have maxes and mins at different places; what you're getting is the sum of the maxes separately, but that's a different thing.  An answer below that is a hybrid of your method and the parabola method is probably what you will want to use - but yes, using critical points is the general way for functions other than quadratics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$x^2-4x+1=(x-2)^2-3.$$So,\begin{align}-4<x<6&\iff-6<x-2<4\\&\iff0\leqslant(x-2)^2<36\\&\iff-3\leqslant(x-2)^2-3<33\\&\iff-3\leqslant x^2-4x+1<33.\end{align}Also, note that here I have only used equivalences. Therefore, I get the actual range and not a set that could be larger than the range.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the quadratic $f(x)=x^2- 4x + 1$ on $\Bbb R$ first: it's a parabola with a minimum, and this minimum lies at $\frac{-b}{2a} = \frac{4}{2} = 2$ and has value $f(2)= 4 - 8 + 1 = -3$. Then on both sides of $x=2$ the function will be increasing to infinity (symmetrically around $x=2$). This should be included in your knowledge of parabolas.

Now the actual domain is $(-4,6)$, so we truncate the values on both sides (with domain $\Bbb R$ the range would have been $[-3, \rightarrow)$, because of the minimum and the shape of the graph). And $f(-4) = 16 + 16 + 1 = 33$ and $f(6) = 36 - 24 + 1 = 13$, so the graph reaches its highest point (almost) at $(-4,33)$ which is just on the boundary of the domain (which is open ended).

All values inbetween $-3$ inclusive and $33$ are assumed on $(-4,2]$ already, then some values are duplicated again on $[2,6)$ as well...

So range of $f$ is $[-3,33)$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-4x+1 = (x-2)^2-3$$
That is a  parabola open upward with a vertex at the point $(2, -3)$

Thus the minimum value of your function on $(-4, 6)$ is attained at $x=2$ and the supremum is $f(6)=33$

Thus $$ -3\le f(x) < 33$$